# Calculate the following double integral

Tags: integration

$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\int_{x}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{y e^y}\,dy \,dx $$

Approach :

I tried it by $dx\ dy$ but didn't help as $x$ goes from $ y\ to\ inf$.
Not sure how to start.
Any clue?

Comment: When you switch the order, the bounds on $x$ are only $0$ to $y$.  Draw a picture if you don't see that.

Comment: Here, $y$ goes from $x$ to $inf$ and $x$ goes from $0$ to $inf$.
After changing $x$ should go from $y$ to $inf$ and $y$ goes from $0$ to $inf$ ?
Am I missing out something ?

Comment: Draw a picture.  The shape is an infinite triangle bounded on the left by $x=0$ and bounded on the right by $x=y$.  So those are the bounds.

Comment: Oh yeah! I got it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\iint_{0\leq x\leq y\leq +\infty}\frac{dx\,dy}{y e^y}=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\int_{0}^{y}\frac{1}{y e^y}\,dx\,dy = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dy}{e^y}=\color{red}{1}$$
by Fubini's Theorem.

Comment: This limits was what I was confused about. @Paul made it clear. Thanks for the solution.